# Regular expression to detect Internet Explorer 11

Tags: php, preg-match, internet-explorer-11

I am using this `preg_match` string

```
preg_match('/Trident/7.0; rv:11.0/',$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

to detect IE11 so I can enable tablet mode for it. However it returns "unknown delimiter 7".

How can I do this without PHP complaining at me?

Comment: That's just telling you it's IE11, not that it's a tablet or even that it is a touch-enabled device. Odds are that there are a lot more IE11 desktop users visiting the page than tablet users. What are the consequences of enabling tablet mode for a desktop user without a touch screen?

Comment: Surprised no one beat me to this, but please do not browser detect. It is a very bad habit to have. Instead I recommend you try responsive design techniques and feature detection to build your application. FWIW I used to be in the camp of a dedicated web site for mobile and desktop. But that quickly fades into massive maintenance, etc. Start mobile first, then scale out. It is easier than you think.

Comment: @ChrisLove, no because google uses browser detection, so does msn and microsoft.com. So why shouldn't I?

Comment: If Google jumps off the Golden Gate should you? You have to realize large organizations like MSFT & Google don't follow best practices through out. I use browser detection to determine if the visitor is on an obsolete browser. If so I serve them a core site, without JavaScript. But current browsers are pretty even these days. Still recommend a responsive, mobile first approach as a complete solution based on my experience trying to solve mobile client design for nearly 4 years now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this really a regular expression or just a literal string? If it's just a string, you can use the [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) function instead.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false) {
    // your code
}
```

If it's a regular expression, you must escape special characters like `/` and `.`

**EDIT:**

You can see in the comments of this answer that the code doesn't detect IE 11 properly in all cases. I didn't actually test it to match it, I've just adjusted the code of the question creator to use `strpos` instead of `preg_match` because it was applied incorrectly.

If you want a reliable way to detect IE 11 please take a look at the other answers.

Comment: Does not match my IE string: Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; ASU2JS; rv:11.0

Comment: here is an access log . the above does not work. this is taken from ie 11 request. `172.16.0.85 - - [30/Jan/2015:16:15:01 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1103 "http://website-dev.uk.aaa.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" 0/3500
`

Answer (score 10):

User-agent string may be reported differently across various platforms or devices. Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx

Just found the following string pattern covering most of the User Agents as reported for IE11 or above (It may not hold true if Microsoft changes its User-agent string again for newer version of IE):

```
if (preg_match("/(Trident\/(\d{2,}|7|8|9)(.*)rv:(\d{2,}))|(MSIE\ (\d{2,}|8|9)(.*)Tablet\ PC)|(Trident\/(\d{2,}|7|8|9))/", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], $match) != 0) {
    print 'You are using IE11 or above.';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be

```
if (preg_match("/Trident\/7.0;(.*)rv:11.0/", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], $match) != 0) {}
```

because sometimes you can see the user agent like this one

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; ASU2JS; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Answer (score 2):

IE11 has touch versions and non-touch versions, this means that the Guilherme Sehn's answer will not work for touch devices.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false)
```

Instead, use this:

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'rv:11.0')     !== false
  && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0;')!== false)
{
    echo "User is on IE11 touch / non-touch";
}
```

This is because any number of parameters could be added between "Trident" and the revision number.

Likewise if you want to check if they're on touch just do a strpos for "Touch;".

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to use another character which is not in regexp string so you don't have to escape your string and easier to read for long ones. So you may use `~` for delimiter:

```
preg_match('~Trident/7.0; rv:11.0~',$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])
```

Another idea is to use [stristr](http://php.net/stristr) function to see if a string occurs in another one

```
stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the middle slash `/` to work in a regular expression that is enclosed by slahses:

```
preg_match( '/Trident\/7.0; rv:11.0/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
```

You could also use `preg_quote()` to escape all special characters in the string:

```
$regexp = sprintf( '/%s/', preg_quote( 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0', '/' ) );
preg_match( $regexp, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: The moment you use `preg_quote` on the entire regular expression is the moment you should realise you don't need a regular expression!

Answer (score 0):

The `/` after `Trident` is being treated as a delimiter. You could escape it:

```
preg_match('/Trident\/7.0; rv:11.0/',$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

Better, however, would be not to use `preg_match`: you don't need it. All you're doing is looking for an invariant substring, which can be done with [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
if (false !== strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], '/Trident/7.0; rv:11.0/')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [browscap project](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap) to get this data myself. It's faster and more reliable