# Detect the use of IE11 without further configs

Tags: php, internet-explorer-11

I need to get client version of the browser.
The code I was using is:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== false) {
    $browser = "Firefox";
} else if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false) {
    $browser = "IE";
} else if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== false) {
    $browser = "Chrome";
}
```

I had made a big search here and found the get_browser function, but it does need some configs files to be made. And I not going to do that on every user. So anyone could help me? Something that I could use to get browser information? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [user-contributed function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125) upvoted most on the [`get_browser()` doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) page?

Comment: Also, the `get_browser()` page mentions where an up-to-date `browscap.ini` file can be found: http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/

Comment: You haven't said why you're detecting the browser, but note that MS changed IE11's UA string specifically because they wanted to break detection scripts. They did this because most browser detection is done because a site wants to provide different output for each browser due to their different capabilities; MSdidn't want sites to detect IE and remove features that IE11 does actually support. This pattern has been repeated multiple times though the history of web browsers: look at the average UA string for proof of that. This demonstrates why feature detection is usually a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that code:

```
 if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false) {
        // your code
    }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19743006/996809)

Comment: This does not cover all user agent strings. Here's one it won't match; Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MAPBJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using browser detection which can easily be forged by the user, why don't you instead use a feature detection libary such as http://modernizr.com which detects the browsers features rather than the user agent.

To detect IE11 using the user agent you can use this code

```
$useragent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
if (strpos($useragent, 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') != -1) {
        // IE11 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read this article [PHP code to get Browser Information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545047/Get-Browser-and-Operating-System-with-PHP), I think this is what you wanted.

Hope this might help you

Thanks

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.